# Does higher cpi give better performance?

Tags: cpu-pipelines, mips

Does higher cpi give better performance?

Lets say there is a code and we can run it by 3 methods.

1 cpi for single cycle

99 cpi for multi cycle

70 cpi for pipeline

Multi cycle has the highest cpi for this code. So is multi cycle method the best for this code?

Comment: Surely lower CPI is better, all other things being equal? But of course it depends. Lower CPI depends on the CPU's ability to schedule more instructions, and higher CPI occasionally means faster clock.

Comment: If All the other things are equal, does lower cpi give the better performance?

Comment: Fewer cycles per instruction is better.

Answer (score 1):

CPI = cycled per instruction. Higher CPI = more cycles = more time to get the work done. So it’s worse.